# How to synchronize pivot table in plain PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

Assume we have these tables

```
Users table
-----------
id  name
-----------
1   xxx
2   yyy
3   ccc
4   bbb
5   aaa

Location table
-------------
id  name
-------------
6   Spain
7   Russia
8   Germany
9   USA

Pivot table
------------------------
id  user_id  location_id
------------------------
1   1        6
2   2        8
3   1        8
4   1        9
5   3        8
```

What I want to achieve is to sync the data in the pivot table.
So exactly I have post request with array of user ids = **[1,5,4]** and location_id = **8**. So I would get the following result

```
[updated] Pivot table
-------------------------
id  user_id  location_id
-------------------------
1   1        6 <-- This one stays
3   1        8
4   1        9
6   5        8 <-- Added
7   4        8 <-- Added

...we deleted the row with location_id=8 and user_id=2 and user=3 because those are not in the users array
```

How can I do add the new ones, delete the ones that are not in the request, and leave the one that already exists with some functionality, just like Laravel has done it in **sync** function.

I know that the easyest way is to get all the users that has that specific location_id, delete all, and than insert once again. Is there some workaround or should I do the newbie way :D

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way to go (actually deleting everything and then inserting the values seems easier and cleaner), but here's one way to do it, if for some reason you want to keep the pivot table ID:

1. Define a unique index for the table, considering both pivot fields (user_id,location_id).
2. Insert all data using [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) user_id = user_id and location_id = location_id, so that if there's duplicate values, mysql will keep them without modifications and will not throw error.
3. Implode the Array IDs from the Request and execute a delete from the table, where data is not in the specified values.